# Is there more elegant way to write statement with overlapping (nested) alternatives?

Tags: bash, sh, case-statement

I want to write case statement with overlapping alternatives.

Quick search on the internet gives me examples with alternatives which is unique and not overlapping, smth like:

```
case $var in
    a) <code> ;;
    b) <code> ;;
    *) <code> ;;
esac
```

But I need scenario where one alternative contains several alternatives and additional work. I figure it this way:

```
case $loglevel in
    [0-7]) <code>
           case $loglevel in
                [0-3] <redirect to /dev/console> 
                ;;
                [4-7] <redirect to /dev/null> 
                ;;
           esac
    ;;
    *) <code> ;;
esac
```

I guess is there any more elegant or rational way to do this. It seems for me that nested case statement for such simple scenario is too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your shell is modern enough, you can use `;;&` instead of `;;` to try the following conditions even if the current one succeeded:

```
#! /bin/bash
loglevel=$1
case $loglevel in
    ([0-7]) echo 0..7
            ;;&
    ([0-4]) echo 0..4
            ;;
    ([5-7]) echo 5..7
            ;;
    (*) echo Ohter
esac
```

Which gives

```
▏~ $ 1.sh 1
0..7
0..4
▏~ $ 1.sh 6
0..7
5..7
```

Comment: For more info on `;;&` and `;&` see https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#index-case

Answer (score 0):

```
commonFunc() {
    <common_code>
}

case $loglevel in
    [0-3] commonFunc
          <redirect to /dev/console> 
    ;;
    [4-7] commonFunc
          <redirect to /dev/null> 
    ;;
    *) <other_code> ;;
esac
```

or:

```
case $loglevel in
    [0-3] needX=1; needY=1 ;;
    [4-7] needX=1; needZ=1 ;;
    *) <other_code> ;;
esac

if [ "$needX" = 1 ]; then
    <common_code> 
fi

if [ "$needY" = 1 ]; then
    <redirect to /dev/console> 
fi

if [ "$needZ" = 1 ]; then
    <redirect to /dev/null>
fi
```